# Highlighting delimiters without spaces before parentheses in user defined language

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I have a problem with custom syntax highlighting in Notepad++.

I want to display text in parentheses in a different color. In **View → User Define Dialogue** I've defined a custom language and set up corresponding delimiters, "(" and ")".

However, the problem is that Notepad++ is highlighting the text between parentheses only when there is a space before the left parenthesis. So for example, in `^reg(ular)?$` `(ular)` is not highlighted, but in `^reg (ular)$` it is.

Is there a way to force Notepad++ to recognize delimiters without the space before parentheses?

Answer (score 3):

If you add open parenthesis, "(", to the list of activated operators in the User Define [sic] Language, then the content will be highlighted between the opening and closing parentheses (which you set as the delimiters).

Answer (score 0):

add ( and ) in Operators 1 es better, then if you select ) in the source, the ( is hightlighted